# Factors on which barrier potential in a p n junction depends

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory

I have a few queries regarding the barrier potential in a [p-n junction diode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction).
[image]

1. Is the barrier potential dependent on temperature? Why/why not?
2. Does the barrier potential depend on doping concentration? Why/Why not?
3. Why is the barrier potential different for different semiconductors?

Basically, what determines the barrier potential for a p-n junction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a homojunction the barrier potential depends on the difference in Fermi levels been the n and p sides. If different materials are used (heterojunction) then there is an additional potential from intrinsic difference in electron affinity.